# gradle :compilePlayBinaryPlayRoutes is not generating all imports

Tags: java, scala, gradle, playframework, sbt

I am switching a play app from SBT to gradle and the routes and reverse routes scala files are not being generated with

```
import _root_.play.libs.F
```

which is causing

```
build/src/play/binary/routesScalaSources/controllers/ReverseRoutes.scala:260: not found: value F
def validate(accountId:F.Option[java.lang.Long]): Call = {
```

I am using gradle 3.5, play: '2.4.8', scala: '2.11' and java: '1.8'. Does anyone know if there is a compatibility issue with or some other known issue that is stopping the import from being added to the generated scala file?

** EDIT **

I found this class RoutesCompile with a method additionalImports but I can't find how to use it in the build.gradle file. (I am super new to gradle, more of a maven guy)

** EDIT 2 **

Based on the Javadoc in the [RoutesCompile](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/platform-play/src/main/java/org/gradle/play/tasks/RoutesCompile.java) class it seems like I should be adding it to the model like this:

```
model {
  components {
    play {
        platform play: '2.4.8', scala: '2.11', java: '1.8'
        injectedRoutesGenerator = true
        additionalImports = ['play.libs.F']
        sources {
            twirlTemplates {
                defaultImports = TwirlImports.JAVA
                source.srcDir "assets/views"
                source.exclude "assets/stylesheets"
            }
        }
     }
   }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
> Exception thrown while executing model rule: play { ... } @ build.gradle line 147, column 9
> No such property: additionalImports for class: org.gradle.play.PlayApplicationSpec
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have finally found the answer to my issue.  I needed to get the task and add the additional import that way.

```
model {
components {
    play {
        platform play: '2.4.8', scala: '2.11', java: '1.8'
        injectedRoutesGenerator = true
        tasks.withType(RoutesCompile) {
            additionalImports = ['play.libs.F']
        }

        sources {
            twirlTemplates {
                defaultImports = TwirlImports.JAVA
                source.srcDir "assets/views"
                source.exclude "assets/stylesheets"
            }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Wish I found this before opening a ticket on the Gradle project.